# When I define a string, the program stops working properly

Tags: c++, string, printing

I am new in programming and now I'm learning from a book written by Bjarne Stroustrup ("2014 Programming Principles And Practice Using C++"). Anyway, the problem I am encountering is about the fact that when I define a string, the program stop working properly. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double i;
    double c = 0;
    double bsf;
    double ssf;

    while (cin >> i) {
        if (c == 0) {
            bsf = i;
            cout <<"The largest so far: " << i<<endl;
        }
        if (c == 1 && i > bsf) {
              ssf = bsf;
            bsf = i;
            cout << "The largest so far: " << i<<endl;
        } else if (c > 0 && i > bsf) {
            bsf = i;
            cout <<"The largest so far: " << i<<endl;
        } else if (c > 0 && i < bsf) {
            if (i < ssf) {
                ssf = i;
                cout <<"The smallest so far: " << i <<endl;
            }
        }
        c++;
    }    
}
```

In CodeBlocks, this program works properly (I want the program to let me insert as many numbers as I want and to specify me when I write the biggest number and, also, the smallest number (you can make a better idea from the code). The problem appears when I try to define, as I said earlier, a string:

```
string um;
```

If I am doing this, the program doesn't recognize the smallest number written. If I write, for example, firstly, the number 220, it will be printed "The largest so far: 220", but if I write after that 45, it will not be printed "The smallest so far: 45".
If you guys can offer me some advices, it would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Horrible indentation - fixed it for you.

Comment: @sandbda please specify where you are declaring the string.

Comment: Add the try containing problem about string instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advices, I am new here and I didn't know these things :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is not undefined behavior as far as I can see. But the total lack of an if clause that caters to the OP's requirement.When the second no is entered, `c` is equal to 1 and in the if clauses there is no code for `i <= bsf`. So the code must be rewritten as

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double i;
    double c = 0;
    double bsf;
    double ssf;

    while (cin >> i) {
        if (c == 0) {
            bsf = i;
            cout <<"The largest so far: " << i <<endl;
        }
        if (c == 1 && i > bsf) {
            ssf = bsf;
            bsf = i;
            cout <<"The largest so far: " << i <<endl;
        } else if(c == 1 && i <= bsf) {
            ssf = i;
            cout <<"The smallest so far: " << i <<endl;
        }  else if (c > 0 && i > bsf) {
            bsf = i;
            cout <<"The largest so far: " <<i <<endl;
        } else if (c > 0 && i < bsf) {
            if (i < ssf) {
                ssf = i;
                cout << "The smallest so far: " << i <<endl;
            }
        }
        c++;
    }    
}
```

This will also curb the UB in @Ron 's answer

*EDIT* : Thank you  @drescherjm i forgot to add <=, that has been corrected

Comment: Thank you very much, WARhead. This part of code you've written was what I needed to write: else if(c == 1 && i < bsf) {
            ssf = i;
            cout <<"The smallest so far: " << i <<endl;}

Comment: @drescherjm case for `i<= bsf` has been added in the last edit.

Answer (score 2):

In your program you are trying to use local variables:

```
double bsf; // uninitialized local variable
double ssf; // uninitialized local variable
```

without initializing them thus causing [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Initialize your (local) variables prior to using them:

```
double bsf = 0;
double ssf = 0;
```

The actual culprit is on line `26`:

```
if (i < ssf) // UB access to uninitialized variable `ssf`
```

Here is a screenshot from Visual Studio with the important info underlined:

[image: UB]
Here is a [GCC version on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b0c9834581718c8).

There is no [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) variable in your program. If there was one you would need to include the `<string>` header.

Comment: @drescherjm The use of variable `ssf` does cause UB.

Comment: In "if (c==1&i>bsf) {" you almost certainly want the & to be &&.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I don't see the problem you are talking about in the code. Not sure if it was edited in the initial edit window or what but I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of **initial values**; this code becomes much simpler if you initialize `bsf` to `DBL_MIN` and initialize `ssf` to `DBL_MAX`. Then as you go through the loop you just have to check the new value against `bsf` and `ssf` without all that confusion involving `c`.